# How to overlap 3 images and align them to bottom of div?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with several sections, and I am trying to overlap three images and align them to the bottom of the first section (see image below).   [image]

Here is the html I have so far:

```
<div id="welcome_graphs">
            <img src="img/blue_graph.png" id="blue_graph">
            <img src="img/red_graph.png" id="red_graph">
            <img src="img/orange_graph.png" id="orange_graph">
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#blue_graph{
        z-index: -100; 
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0; 
    }
    #red_graph{
        z-index: -80;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0; 
    }
    #orange_graph{
        z-index: -70; 
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0; 
    }
    #welcome_graphs{
        position: absolute;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

Right now they are overlapping but I can't get them aligned to the bottom of the section.

Comment: Please add HTML/CSS of sections area, ideally as working fiddle.

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jak5usyf/

Comment: Actually in you telling me to make a fiddle I figured out how to align them to the bottom now all I'm trying to do is center them all.

Comment: set left: 0px; right: 0px; margin: auto; on the images

Comment: Thank you vals, that did the trick. updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jak5usyf/

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that all 3 images are the same height and all sitting at

`bottom:0;`

what you need to do is apply different bottom values OR different heights.

```
#first {
    z-index:-30;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    border:solid black 1px;
}
#second {
    z-index: -40;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    border:solid black 1px;
}
#third {
    z-index: -50;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    border:solid black 1px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of what I mean: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jak5usyf/2/)